# Move the commit from username to another?

Tags: git, git-commit

I've recently modified my git username. I was wondering if there is a way to move my commits under my old username to the new one?

Comment: From [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git) you'll want to follow the script that GitHub has provided [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/).

Comment: See also [this `.mailmap` suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427247/how-to-change-committed-user-name-in-bitbucket/30373772#30373772), which should let you solve this without rewriting any history.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git